# Creating landing page of an attribute of products, following the concept of the category page

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, product-list

The products have the brand attribute, you could create a page to list all the products of this brand?

Or this will be possible only through a category of marks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with the category approach. This does not involve any coding but it gets kind of hard to manage when you have a lot of products.
Or you can go with the extension approach.
I can recommend you [this free extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/rule-products).
It allows you to create pages with products based on rules. The rule definition is similar to how you define a catalog discount rule.
The pages will look like any other catalog page with sorting and filtering and it supports SEF url's
All you have to do is to create a rule for each brand you have.
The rule can look like this:

```
if all of these conditions are true
    brand is {your brand here}
```

[Documentation can be found here](https://github.com/tzyganu/rule-products/wiki)